# I want to issue a validation error message

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I registered an error message but I don't know how to output it
**WorkController.php**

```
public function store(CreateWorkRequest $request,$id)
{
    $v = $request->WorkRequest();
    return redirect()->route('work.index', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

**CreateWorkRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'work_time' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
    ];
}
public function messages() {
    return [
        'work_time' => ':Required',
        'content    ' => ':Required',
    ];
}
```

Output here
**workindex.blade.php**

```
<label for="work_time">work_time</label>
<input id="work_time" type="time" name="work_time" value="{{old('work_time')}}">

<label for="content">content</label>
<textarea id="content" name="content" cols="120" row="20"></textarea>
```

I would like to know where to edit

Comment: What's the question exactly? Don't you know where to output the error message (tip: Laravel does that for you if you work with Request classes) or don't you know where to edit the translations?

Comment: you want to edit the error message?  and want to show it on the frontend?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that this is a QA site, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer. Then, please edit your question.

Comment: @Loek I want to output to blade

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I want to output to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can show the error in a span.

```
<label for="work_time">work_time</label>
<input id="work_time" type="time" name="work_time" value="{{old('work_time')}}">
@if ($errors->has('work_time'))
    <span class="is-invalid">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('work_time') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

And you can customize your error messages too.

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'work_time.required' => 'Work Time is Required',
            .....................................
        ];
    }
```